# Manipulating strings python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to code a program that will insert specific numbers before parts of an input, for example given the input "171819-202122-232425"  I would like it to split up the number into pieces and use the dash as a delimiter.  I have split up the number using list(str(input)) but have no idea how to insert the appropriate numbers.  It has to work for any number Thanks for the help.

Output =

```
     (number)17
     (number)18                
     (number)19
     (number+1)20
     (number+1)21
     (number+1)22
     (number+2)23
     (number+2)24
     (number+2)25
```

Comment: Add a `number` every 2 digits in the input? That's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could use split and regexps to dig out lists of your numbers:

### Code

```
import re

mynum = "171819-202122-232425"
start_number = 5
groups = mynum.split('-') # list of numbers separated by "-"
number_of_groups = xrange(start_number , start_number + len(groups))

for (i, number_group) in zip(number_of_groups, groups):
    numbers = re.findall("\d{2}", number_group) # return list of two-digit numbers
    for x in numbers:
            print "(%s)%s" % (i, x)
```

### Result

```
(5)17
(5)18
(5)19
(6)20
(6)21
(6)22
(7)23
(7)24
(7)25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
mInput = "171819-202122-232425"
number = 9 # Just an example
result = ""

i = 0
for n in mInput:
    if n == '-': # To handle dash case
        number += 1
        continue
    i += 1
    if i % 2 == 1: # Each two digits
        result += "\n(" + str(number) + ")" 
    result += n # Add current digit

print result
```

**Output:**

```
(9)17
(9)18
(9)19
(10)20
(10)21
(10)22
(11)23
(11)24
(11)25
```